# Debugging Windows Phone 7 device traffic with Fiddler

Tags: windows-phone-7, fiddler

I followed all the steps from the article but when I try to hit the server from my windows phone it says there is a dns error.

Article for reference.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2011/01/09/debugging-windows-phone-7-device-traffic-with-fiddler.aspx

How do I know my windows phone is using my local LAN WIFI as opposed to ATT cellular?

Comment: I have correctly set the proxy server and port on windows phone 7. I tested the same with my other windows box on the LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I use Netmon 2.3 for network traffic information from WP7. Fiddler didn't support WP7 up until recently and Netmon/Wireshark did, so I just stick with those.

Using Netmon 2.3, while your device is connected to Zune/WPConnect, you'd be able to see all WP7 device transport on the ZuneComm process. Netmon isn't as user-friendly as Fiddler, but it's fairly darn specific and easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn on flight mode and then turn wifi back on.
Or you could take the sim out.

Either of those ways will ensure you're not using the cellular network.

Comment: No luck. It still says " 'We can't display this page right now' Error: Cannot find server or DNS error."

Answer (score 0):

I used the IP address instead of dns and it worked.

Comment: can you explain this a little more? Which IP address did you use (the host machine or the router)? Did you have to make any changes to the router settings, such as setting up port forwarding?